# X11 lib - How to obtain PID of the current window?

Tags: haskell, x11, pid

How to obtain PID of the current window using [X11 lib](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/X11)?

I tried checking the `_NET_WM_PID` property of the window and its parents and it was always unset.

Comment: You can try _NET_WM_PID but chances it will work are rather slim, given that _NET_WM_NAME is not set. (_NET_WM_NAME has nothing to do with PIDs) In general, it is not possible to do reliably, or even define precisely what it means.

Comment: @n.m. Thank you, that was a copy/typo, it was supposed to say `_NET_WM_PID`. I updated it now.

Comment: Please note that if you get a value in `_NET_WM_PID` you don't know if you can use it yet. It might not be for your machine. See `ssh -X`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I figured out what I was doing wrong.
Code adapted from [ARBTT](https://github.com/nomeata/arbtt):

```
getParent :: Display -> Window -> IO Window
getParent dpy w = do
  (_, parent, _) <- queryTree dpy w `catchIOError` const (return (0,0,[]))
  return parent

followTreeUntil :: Display -> (Window -> IO Bool) -> Window -> IO Window
followTreeUntil dpy cond = go
  where go w = do
          match <- cond w
          if match
            then return w
            else
              do p <- getParent dpy w
                 if p == 0 then return w
                           else go p

getFocusedWindowPID :: Display -> IO String
getFocusedWindowPID d = do
  (w, _) <- getInputFocus d
  wt <- followTreeUntil d (hasCorrectPID d) w
  getWindowPID d wt

getWindowPID :: Display -> Window -> IO String
getWindowPID d w = do
  nWP <- internAtom d "_NET_WM_PID" False
  pid' <- getWindowProperty32 d nWP w
  let pid = case pid' of
              Just [pid''] -> show pid''
              _            -> ""
  return pid

hasCorrectPID :: Display -> Window -> IO Bool
hasCorrectPID d w = do
  pid <- getWindowPID d w
  return $ pid /= ""

printPIDs :: IO ()
printPIDs = do
  d <- openDisplay ""
  pid <- getFocusedWindowPID d
  print pid
  closeDisplay d
  threadDelay 1000000
  printPIDs
```

This will display the PID of the focused window once every second.

Answer (score 3):

It can't be reliably done, due to architectural decisions made by the X11 team. For example, the process that created a window may not even be on the same machine as the X11 server (and who knows if the OS of the machine it's running on even has a concept of PIDs?); and besides that there's not really a concept of "ownership" in X11, as any program can do anything to any window.

Comment: We know for sure that PID can be obtained at least as reliable as running `xprop _NET_WM_PID` and then clicking on a window is. So there are ways, we just need the code to achieve that.

Comment: @RăzvanFlaviusPanda if you can do xprop _NET_WM_PID, you shoould be able to do the same with XGetWindowRoperty. If you in fact cannot, there is a problem with your code and you should ask a question about a problem in your code, showing a [mcve].

Comment: @RăzvanFlaviusPanda Sure. But the question explicitly says, "I tried checking the `_NET_WM_PID` and it was always unset"... so I took that as true. If it's not, well... that's on you, isn't it? =P (And anyway I wouldn't consider that "reliable" at all.)

Comment: @n.m. Before answering you could have asked in comments if it was unclear what I was asking for or wanted more information. How do you suggest we proceed now so this question does not become useless (eg. without proper answers)? What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

There is no good way to get the PID of an X11 window; and if there were it would not be immediately useful because the process is not guaranteed to be on the same machine, and may not even be resolvable from the machine your process is running on.

The old `xhost` mechanism is virtually gone from modern usage, but the concept is very much alive. `ssh -X` is very much in use and you may have to deal with the fact that both your process and the target process are running under different instances of `ssh -X`, potentially under different users. This leaves no path to resolve target.

However, if you got here because you need to kill the process, you are (kind of) in luck. The process can be dumped from the X11 session (which terminates it in the default handler) by calling `XKilLClient` on the target window.

```
int XKillClient(Display *display, XID resource);
```

The first argument is your connection to the X server. The second argument is any window (or any other resource) of the process you want gone. See `man 3 XKillClient` for more details.

After reading comment, I feel like I am obliged to point out that `_NET_WM_PID` is completely unreliable. At this moment I have a window on my desktop for which `_NET_WM_PID` reports 1. This now sounds like a horrible XY problem. The C API function to retrieve a property is `XGetWindowProperty`, which you would call to get things like window title.

Comment: We know for sure that PID can be obtained at least as reliable as running `xprop _NET_WM_PID` and then clicking on a window is. So there are ways, we just need the code to achieve that.